# How to set the initial X-axis value for a .NET fastline chart?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I use .AddY to plot the values of 150 Y values.
The x axis legend at the bottom has 0   50   100   150.

How can I make it start with an arbitrary number other than 0?

Comment: _NET fastline chart_ are yopu talking about MSChart? If so you can set the axis.Interval. Also: Do use the AddXY overload or else you can't control the x-values!!

Comment: I don't remember what MSChart is anymore.  I'm using .Net Namespace:
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score -1):

[TaW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3152130/taw) said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62329604/how-to-set-the-initial-x-axis-value-for-a-net-fastline-chart/62330702#comment110236405_62329604):

> use the AddXY overload or else you can't control the x-values!!